# The setState() doesn't change the state mocha + Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, setstate

I'm testing a function who reset all the components. My problem is, when I try to set a state with:

```
wrapper.dive().setState({'startHour': ['5']})
```

this doesn't change anything if then I use

```
wrapperS.dive().state().startHour
```

Any ideas on that?

Comment: what does wrapper.dive() return?

Comment: Hi Dae, now I could solve the issue. I was reading the state wrong. This was I done and works to me now.

// Change de state value to 5
`var newValue = await wrapperS.dive().setState({startHour: 5})`

 // Evaluate the change
`expect(newValue.instance().state.startHour).to.deep.equal(5)`

// Run the resetFilter
`var reset = await newValue.instance().resetFilter()`

// Evaluate the value with changes
`expect(newValue.instance().state.startHour).to.deep.equal(1)`

Thank you, anyway

Comment: [Out of context]: I would recommend using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/) to write tests for UI components in a user-centric way.